# pairwise orthogonal projections in an inseparable $C^* $ algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a separable  $C^*$ algebra,then there are at most countable pairwise orthogonal projections.If $A$ is inseparable,how many pairwise orthogonal projections in $A$? If it has, is it  uncountable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may have zero. For instance, take 
$$
A=\prod_{t\in[0,1]} C_0(\mathbb R). 
$$
With the norm $\|a\|=\sup\{\|a_t\|:\ t\in[0,1]\}$, this is a non-separable C$^*$-algebra. And it has no projections other that $0$, since any projection has to be a product of projections and $C_0(\mathbb R)$ has no nonzero projections.

As s.harp mentions, any family of pairwise orthogonal projections will have cardinality less than or equal that of $A$.

Comment: Also: the upper bound should be given by the cardinality of $A$.

Comment: Indeed. I edited that in.

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space, then the C*-algebra $B(H)$ of all operators on $H$ is not separable, but any orthogonal family of nonzero projections must be countable. However, if $K(H)$ is the ideal of all compact operators on $H$, then there is an uncountable orthogonal family of projections in $B(H)/K(H)$.
If $A$ is a separable C*-algebra then $A$ can be embedded in $B(H)$, so any orthogonal family of nonzero projections must be countable.